# Running Sparkling-Water with external H2O backend

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I was following the steps for running Sparkling water with external backend from [here](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/doc/backends.md#manual-mode-of-external-backend). I am using `spark 1.4.1`, `sparkling-water-1.4.16`, I've build the extended h2o jar and exported the `H2O_ORIGINAL_JAR` and `H2O_EXTENDED_JAR` system variables. I start the h2o backend with

```
java -jar $H2O_EXTENDED_JAR -md5skip -name test
```

But when I start sparkling water via

```
./bin/sparkling-shell
```

and in it try to get the `H2OConf` with

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
val conf = new H2OConf(sc).setExternalClusterMode().useManualClusterStart().setCloudName("test”)
val hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(sc, conf)
```

it fails on the second line with

```
<console>:24: error: trait H2OConf is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   val conf = new H2OConf(sc).setExternalClusterMode().useManualClusterStart().setCloudName("test")
              ^
```

I've tried adding the newly build extended h2o jar with `--jars` parameter either to sparkling water or standalone spark with no progress. Does any one have any hints?

Comment: The tutorial is only few minor versions old, at the time of `sparkling-water-1.4.16` the class was still abstract and therefore unusable in this way.

Comment: External cluster is now supported only in 2.+ SW version (to some extend it will be available in SW1.6). Any reasons for using 1.4 version of Spark - it is really old (with respect to current state of Spark ecosystem).

Comment: Legacy system is the reason. We are planning upgrade in the near future, but we don't have enough time right now.

Comment: Right now, we are not planning to back port the change into older Spark releases. However, technically it is not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsupported for versions of Spark earlier than 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of sparkling jar and add it to while starting the spark-shell:

```
./bin/sparkling-shell --master yarn-client --jars "<path to the jar located>"
```

Then run the code by setting the extended h2o driver:

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o._

val conf = new H2OConf(spark).setExternalClusterMode().useAutoClusterStart().setH2ODriverPath("//home//xyz//sparkling-water-2.2.5/bin//h2odriver-sw2.2.5-hdp2.6-extended.jar").setNumOfExternalH2ONodes(2).setMapperXmx("6G")

val hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark, conf)
```